# Jquery $(this) not working inside function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-waypoints

I am trying to use waypoints.js to have elements fadein when scrolling to hit the elements.

I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.card').waypoint(function(down) {
    console.log('hit element');
    $(this).addClass('card-fadeIn');
}, { offset: '100%' });

});
```

What this does is adds the class 'card-fadeIn' which is opacity 1 and an ease in animation.

When I change it to

```
$('.card').addClass('card-fadeIn');
```

It works fine, but adds opacity 1 to every card class and ruins the fadein effect.  I was trying to use $(this) instead but it wont fadein, nor will it give an error in the console.  Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you log what this is inside that function?

Comment: `this` could be very different to what you think it is.

Comment: `this` is probably not the jQuery object scope anymore. Save `this` in some variable before.

Comment: I think, because in this case `this` is the `waypoint`. Console log `this` to inspect what is that. Try to pass the element to that function.

Comment: Yep console log gives me element and a few other options

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use

```
$(this.element)
```

in a Waypoint handler. So,

```
$(this.element).addClass('card-fadeIn');
```

should do what you want.

`$(this)` works inside jQuery callbacks because jQuery is designed for things to work that way. There's nothing magic about it, however, so if `this` doesn't refer to a DOM element, you'll get a jQuery object that won't do anything (and which won't report any errors, because, again, that's just how jQuery works). The Waypoint library binds `this` to its own context object, and that exposes a reference to the DOM element involved in the callback as the "element" property.

Comment: this.element adds the correct css to it, however it applies the animation to every .card element, I just want to have it trigger on scrolling down.

Comment: @ServerSideSkittles I don't understand what you mean. You haven't posted your HTML and I don't have a good idea what exactly it is that you want the page to do. Have you used Waypoint before?

Comment: First time using waypoint.  I have this theme http://ashobiz.asia/flatmania151/theme/index.html and want to replicate the effect on another theme.  From what I can tell the theme uses this exact method.  I have removed the other js piece by piece and all it uses is css opacity, jquery waypoints and custom function similar to my own.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this.element?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.card').waypoint(function(down) {
    console.log('hit element');
    $(this.element).addClass('card-fadeIn');
}, { offset: '100%' });

});
```