# Cannot add class to next element of $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class, next to checked input. So, class will be added to span, which is next to a checked input radio.

```
<label>
 <input type="radio" name="option[228]" value="20" checked="checked">
 <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Purple (+₹20)">
    <img src="http://countrylivings.com/image/cache/catalog/sample/q2-50x50.png" alt="Purple +₹20" width="36px" height="36px">
 </span>
</label>
```

I have tried a no. of ways to do so... But didn't work. like---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('label input').is(':checked')) {
        $(this.element).next().addClass('hloo');
        alert($(this.element).val());
    };
});
```

But i get an alert of **undefined** when input is *checked*.
So,

```
if ($('label input').is(':checked')) {
```

is working fine to detect if checkbox is checked But

```
$(this) or $(this.element)
```

is not working.
Anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: `this` would refer to `document` and I don't know what you expect `this.element` to be but it probably does not exist. Maybe you want `$('label input:checked').next().addClass('hloo');`

Comment: I just tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968289/jquery-this-not-working-inside-function

Comment: That seems to be about a specific jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's three issues in your code. Firstly `::checked` is not a valid jQuery selector, it's just `:checked`.

Secondly, assuming `this` is a reference to an Element object (as it is in the vast majority of cases in jQuery) then there is no `element` property. Just use `$(this)`.

Lastly, `if` conditions run under the outer scope, so `this` would refer to the `document` in your example, not the `input`. It's for this reason `val()` is undefined; you're looking at `document.value`. To fix this, select the element directly before working with it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $checkedInput = $('label input:checked');
  $checkedInput.next().addClass('hloo');
  console.log($checkedInput.val());
});
```

```css
.hloo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
 <input type="radio" name="option[228]" value="20" checked="checked">
 <span data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Purple (+₹20)">
  <img src="http://countrylivings.com/image/cache/catalog/sample/q2-50x50.png" alt="Purple +₹20" width="36px" height="36px">
 </span>
</label>
```

Comment: No  problem, glad to help